# What columns to index on to make this query faster?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-indexes

```
SELECT t.compname, min(t2.version) FROM archdetails t
INNER JOIN svn3 b ON t.compname = b.compname
INNER JOIN archdetails t2 ON t.compname = t2.compname
WHERE ((b.revno = '270294' OR b.revno = 'r275869' OR b.revno = 'r393316'))
  AND t.version = '1.6'
GROUP BY t.compname`
```

Table `archdetails`:

```
Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra  
-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------  
name                     | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |  
compname                 | varchar(500) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |  
sno                      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
count                    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
fdindex                  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
version                  | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |  
sdate                    | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |  
edate                    | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |  
inFlat                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
inStar                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
inNostar                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |  
inReducedStar            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |
```

Table `svn3`:

```
Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra  
---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+------  
name     | varchar(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |  
revno    | varchar(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |  
comp     | varchar(1000) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |  
compname | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NA      |
```

I have `1` index on `compname version` in `archdetails` and  `4` indexes on `svn3` on `revno`; `revno, comp, compname`; `comp, compname`; and `name, revno, comp, compname`.

The indexes on compname is of length 100.

The query still takes `0.16 sec` to execute which is very expensive for my purpose. I don't have much experience with indexes and the above indexes have been created with variables most often used. Please advise on how to go about indexes.

Comment: Nice edit. How do you do that?. I am still learning to format here.

Comment: Four spaces at the beginning of a line will make a code block, or you can click on the "010" button in the editing toolbar. FYI the bright orange question mark box is a link to the formatting cheat sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Stack Overflow does syntax highlighting, but I cleaned up your SQL by hand--line breaks are your friends.

Comment: My experience with mySql is not good. Have you considered MS Sql Server Express version? It is free, and allows DB sized up to 4 gig. I switched to SQL Server and found it to be MUCH faster.

Comment: I dont see the purpose of the second innerjoin. Try explain and see if your index is beeing used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer: Include fields that are in your where clause.

In your case, consider indexing svn3.revno and archdetails.version.  Then look at the columns in your join. Index archdetails.compname is one to consider, too.

Of course you don't want to add too many indexes. They make your inserts and deletes slower, and make your DB take more space.

Comment: Yeah thats the good part. Space no constraint. Inserts and deletes are very rare

Comment: A brief article on indexes: http://rip747.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/optmizing-your-database-with-indexes/

Comment: In case you missed my comment under your question, consider moving to the free Express version of MS SQL Server.  You will probably get far better query performance than you get from MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.compname,
t.version
FROM archdetails t
INNER JOIN svn3 b 
        ON t.compname 
         = b.compname 
WHERE b.revno in ('270294','r275869','r393316')
AND t.version = '1.6'
```